# Express: Do I just define app.use(cors()) or do I need to router.use(cors()) for every route?

Tags: node.js, express, routes, cors

Short question. I'm building this app and it's getting quite large and messy so I'd like to reduce it. I have app.use(cors()) in server.js and define router.use(cors()) for every route that I have. Can I remove router.use(cors()) on every route and not have a cors error by only having app.use(cors()) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One copy of:

```
app.use(cors());
```

That occurs BEFORE any of your route or router definitions are registered will automatically apply to all your route definitions whether they are `app.xxx()` or `router.xxx()`.

Middleware is run in the order you register it so as long as `app.use(cors())` runs before you register any of your routers, it will automatically apply to all of your routers.

This, of course, assumes that you want CORs access to apply to all your routes, not just some of them.

It's also worth mentioning that `app.use(cors());` is sufficient for some CORs access, but not all types of CORs access so it also depends upon exactly what the CORs requests are doing.

Answer (score 0):

You will not get any error if you have app.use(cors()) only in server.js file.